# Data Model's "serialize" function not called on property "set"ting

Tags: javascript, extjs

Also asked on Sencha's site [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301707-Data-Model-s-quot-serialize-quot-function-not-called-on-write-to-server)

My data model's "serialize" function is not called when I call

```
model.set("<fieldName>", <newValue>);
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nrj)

I'm pretty unclear on why the serialize function isn't called...**am I missing something, or *is this a bug?***

(And here's the code from the fiddle)

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    requires: [
        "Ext.data.Store"
    ],

    launch : function() {

            var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {          
            data: [{Id: 0, Name: "Bill", Props: "{foo: 2, bar:{pan:5}}"}],


            fields:[

                {name: "Id", type: "int"},
                {name: "Name", type: "string"},
                {name: "Props", 
                 convert: function(value, record){
                     console.log("called convert");
                    return Ext.JSON.decode(value);
                 },
                 serialize: function(value, record){
                     alert("never getting called!! :(");
                     console.log("sure, i'll put log here too..not getting called though");
                     return Ext.JSON.encode(value);
                 }
                }
            ]        
        });

        console.log(store.getAt(0));
        var rec = store.getAt(0);
        var newProp = {rec:"junk", foo: "orange"};
        console.log(newProp);
        rec.set("Props",newProp);


    }
});
```

Comment: You're missing a few things, 1) Your sample code throws exceptions in `convert`. 2) You're not doing anything to trigger the data to be saved to the server. You would need to call `rec.save();` 3) You don't have a proxy configured for anything to get posted to a server.

Comment: Please note that 1. it only throws the exception after an attempt is made to set the field. The first time the store loads the inline records into itself, (and thus calls the convert function) the properties are extracted from the JSON string just fine. 2. You're right, I didn't. I don't agree that i "need to call rec.save();" since the issue isn't with persisting, but assigning properties. 3. See 2. Unnecessary since it's local. 
My understanding of ExtJS's model system was that mappings were automatically created.. this appears to not be the case.

Comment: I updated the title to reflect what I *actually* meant to ask..thank you for your input

Comment: In that case it's working as intended. Serialize is only supposed to be called when the data is about to be written back to the server.

Comment: Right..I understand that now...it's annoying. IMHO data models ought to allow for a setConvert function to be supplied along with the convert function..doesn't make sense to allow converts from one direction but not the other.

Comment: It does get run: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nu0

Comment: Of course it gets run. I'm not arguing that it doesn't. That's the whole point of my first comment. I'm saying that there *should* be a user-configurable convert-like function that is called when a property is "set"; solely then and never else. The current convert function should also remain so that when the property is read, it may be manipulated to whatever form is needed.

Hence my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappings from source content (JSON/XML) to business model (Ext.data.Model) are not automatically created in ExtJS's data model system. As such, another step is needed to produce this relationship using mapping/associationsor something similar.

I.e. The data model doesn't store the original JSON to read/write from, which is fine for most cases. When a JSON string needs to be updated via ExtJS, one solution is to, on the model, set

```
   convertOnSet
```

to false, allowing for custom manipulation of the JSON string via extract/update functions on the data model.